# python - How do I perform the calculation using shift function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, shift

below is the df

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'Sr. No': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                    'val1' : [2,3,2,4,1,2],

})
```

I want Val2 such that the first row is same as first row of val1
but but row 2 and below the formula is as show in the pic. I am assuming it should be an easy one with shift, but just not getting my head around this.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is `mul` and `cumsum`:

```
df["new"] = df["Sr. No"].mul(df["val1"]).cumsum()

print (df)

   Sr. No  val1  new
0       1     2    2
1       2     3    8
2       3     2   14
3       4     4   30
4       5     1   35
5       6     2   47
```

Comment: that was must helpful, however what if I change the formula to C2+B3^A3 (and likewise C3 + B4^A4...all the down for all rows) ? (if you want I can create a new thread with that updated requirement)

Comment: That makes no difference as long as you change `mul` to your preferred method, in this case `pow`. You can also do `(df[“Sr. No”]**df[“val1”]).cumsum()`.

Comment: perfect! that was most helpful. btw only edit is it should be (df['val1']**df['Sr. No']).cumsum()

Comment: btw I have added a more complex version of this in the new thread if you are interested https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64737384/python-how-do-i-perform-the-below-operation-in-python-dataframe