# python - how do I perform the below operation in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

below is my df

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'Sr. No': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                    'val1' : [2,3,2,4,1,2],

})
```

I want output val2 as show in the below figures. row1 is same as row1 of val1 but row2 and below is calculated using a formula, as shown

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: just write a `for` loop and do the calculation in plain python

Comment: no that will be inefficient, I got over 30k lines. something along the lines of shift might be more relevant, but not able to get the head around it,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So all rows are dependent on the previous as C4 depends on the calculation of C3 for instance. So what we can do is to operate on the numpy arrays directly.

```
sr_no_vals = df['Sr. No'].values
val1_vals = df['val1'].values
val2_vals = [val1_vals[0]]

for i in range(1, len(sr_no_vals)):
    calculated_value = (((1 + val2_vals[i - 1]) ** sr_no_vals[i - 1]) * (1 + val1_vals[i])) ** (1 / sr_no_vals[i]) 
    val2_vals.append(calculated_value)

df['val2'] = val2_vals
```

When operating with numpy arrays, we can also use a just-in-time compiler such as numba to speed up the operation by a huge factor for large data.

```
@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def calc_val2(val1_vals, sr_no_vals):
    val2_vals = [val1_vals[0]]
    for i in range(1, len(sr_no_vals)):
        calculated_value = (((1 + val2_vals[i - 1]) ** sr_no_vals[i - 1]) * (1 + val1_vals[i])) ** (1 / sr_no_vals[i]) 
        val2_vals.append(calculated_value)
    return val2_vals

df['val2'] = calc_val2(val1_vals, sr_no_vals)
```

Comment: thanks, that was v helpful. I usually try and avoid loops but hopefully with numba should be able to speed up the operation. the only edit to your code will be calculated value should be : calculated_value = (((1 + val2_vals[i - 1]) ** sr_no_vals[i - 1]) * (1 + val1_vals[i])) ** (1 / sr_no_vals[i])

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I fixed the formula. Usually, it is great practice to avoid for loops, you indeed are right there. I wish I knew / there was a way this would work without it.

Comment: would be keen to hear if there is a faster way! thanks again